# Apache2 -> Tomcat Virtual Host

Tags: apache, tomcat, proxy, virtualhost

I'm trying to set up an issue tracker on my server, running apache2.  However, the issue tracker (youtrack) runs in tomcat, so I am trying to set up a virtual host that will redirect to the tomcat server. This is what I've got:

```
#Tomcat                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName issues.example.ca
    ServerAlias issues.example.*

    ProxyRequests Off
    <Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>

    ProxyPass / http://www.example.com:8080/youtrack/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://www.example.com:8080/youtrack/
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyStatus On
    <Location />
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Location>

    ErrorLog logs/issues.example.ca-error_log
    CustomLog logs/issues.example.ca-access_log common

</VirtualHost>
```

Now, I can see the youtrack login page, but without their CSS applied, and I can't log in. I poked around in the source and it turns out that it looks for all its resources in `/youtrack` which obviously doesnt exist because that means it would be looking in `http://example.com:8080/youtrack/youtrack`. How would I go about getting rid of this second youtrack path?  I have tried a rewrite, but I can't quite seem to get it right. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

EDIT: I maanged to do a rewrite like this:

```
RewriteRule ^.*/youtrack/(.*)$ /$1 [P,L]
```

And the site works, but now the problem is that the url reads `issues.example.com/youtrack/stuff` and I would like it to be `issues.example.com/stuff`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change URI on the server where YouTrack run from /youtrack to /.
This is only way to achieve what you need.

Then, replace 
"ProxyPass / http://www.example.com:8080/youtrack/" 
with 
"ProxyPass / http://www.example.com:8080/"
etc...

Answer (score 0):

In past, we use modjk to bridge Apache and Tomcat.

I didn't work on this configuration for years, so that maybe there are some newer method.